merge columns with same name in pandas
I have a dataframe which consists of a couple of columns with same name i.e.
items_group quanity items_group quanity 
KIT1259 0       
KIT1260 0       
KIT1261 0       
                       KIT1151  1
                       KIT1198A 4
                       KIT1198D 5
                       KIT1243  29
                       KIT1249  8

How do I merge them and have only one column of each?
I tried
    df_expanded2 = df_expanded2.stack().dropna().unstack()

But this gives the following error sometimes:
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend copy/reports/views.py", line 1890, in get
    df_expanded2 = df_expanded2.stack().dropna().unstack()
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4157, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 491, in unstack
    unstacker = _Unstacker(
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 192, in _make_selectors
    raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape


Can you please [edit] your question and provide the output of df_expanded2.to_dict('tight') for reproducibility?

Assuming unique indices, this might mean two things:

you don't have empty cells (NaN/None) but empty strings.

Replace them with None:
out = df_expanded2.replace('', None).stack().dropna().unstack()


you have rows with non-null values in more than one column of a give name

Take the first one:
out = df_expanded2.stack(dropna=True).groupby(level=[0, 1]).first().unstack()

Output:
  items_group quanity
0     KIT1259       0
1     KIT1260       0
2     KIT1261       0
3     KIT1151       1
4    KIT1198A       4
5    KIT1198D       5
6     KIT1243      29
7     KIT1249       8


You can also try to split and concat these columns by doing this:
df1 = df.iloc[:, :2]  
df2 = df.iloc[:, 2:]  

df2.columns = df1.columns

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

df_final = df_final.dropna(how='all')

print(df_final)

Output
 items_group quanity
0 KIT1259 0
1 KIT1260 0
2 KIT1261 0
3 KIT1151 1
4 KIT1198A 4
5 KIT1198D 5
6 KIT1243 29
7 KIT1249 8

